# Get the maximum of a function with Newton Raphson

Tags: optimization, newton-raphson

I am having troubles with this exercise.

I have to get the maximum of this function on [-1,2] doing Newton Raphson:

$f(x) = 12 - 3x^4 - 2x^6$

So the derivatives are:

$f'(x) = -12x^3 - 12x^5$

$f''(x) = -36x^2 - 60x^4$

I don't know how to apply the **hessian matrix** and how to solve this problem. Could you help me?

Comment: **HINT** If $f(x)$ has a maximum at $x_0$, then $f'(x_0)=0$

Comment: Not sure where Newton Raphson comes in to it, seems easy to do it directly.

Comment: Important to note:  it is not sufficient, or at least not obviously sufficient, to solve $f'(x)=0$ as has been suggested.  Yes, you have to solve that but you can't neglect the possibility that the maximum occurs at one of the end points.

Comment: The Hessian is just a scalar for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f'(x)=-12 x^3 (1 + x^2)=0$ at $x=0$

The first non zero derivative has an *even* order

$f^{(4)}(x)=-720 x^2-72$

Which is negative at $x=0$, so $x=0$ is a point of maximum and

$f(0)=12$ is the maximum attained by the function

Answer (score 0):

solving the equation $$-12x^3-12x^5=0$$ we have $$-12x^3(1+x^2)=0$$ the only real solution is $$x=0$$